# Transaction is not cancelling on Uniswap

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

I have cancelled a transaction approval request for DAI stable coin on Metamask, but Uniswap is still waiting for the approval.

How should I cancel the transaction on Uniswap?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page.?